# ActiveModel Serializer - Passing params to serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

**AMS version: 0.9.7**

I am trying to pass a parameter to an ActiveModel serializer without any luck.

My (condensed) controller:

```
class V1::WatchlistsController < ApplicationController
  
   def index
     currency = params[:currency]
     @watchlists = Watchlist.belongs_to_user(current_user)
     render json: @watchlists, each_serializer: WatchlistOnlySerializer
   end
```

My serializer:

```
class V1::WatchlistOnlySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :created_at, :market_value
  attributes :id

  
  def filter(keys)
    keys = {} if object.active == false 
    keys
  end 
  
  private

  def market_value
    # this is where I'm trying to pass the parameter
    currency = "usd"
    Balance.watchlist_market_value(self.id, currency)
  end
```

I am trying to pass a parameter `currency` from the controller to the serializer to be used in the `market_value` method (which in the example is hard-coded as "usd").

I've tried @options and @instance_options but I cant seem to get it work. Not sure if its just a syntax issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**AMS version: 0.10.6**

Any options passed to `render` that are not reserved for the `adapter` are available in the serializer as `instance_options`.

In your controller:

```
def index
  @watchlists = Watchlist.belongs_to_user(current_user)
  render json: @watchlists, each_serializer: WatchlistOnlySerializer, currency: params[:currency]
end
```

Then you can access it in the serializer like so:

```
def market_value
  # this is where I'm trying to pass the parameter
  Balance.watchlist_market_value(self.id, instance_options[:currency])
end
```

Doc: [**Passing Arbitrary Options To A Serializer**](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/howto/passing_arbitrary_options.md)

---

**AMS version: 0.9.7**

Unfortunately for this version of AMS, there is no clear way of sending parameters to the serializer. But you can hack this using any of the keywords like `:scope` ([as Jagdeep said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47567199/1977104)) or `:context` out of the [following accessors](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.9.7/lib/active_model/serializer.rb#L156):

```
attr_accessor :object, :scope, :root, :meta_key, :meta, :key_format, :context, :polymorphic
```

Though I would prefer `:context` over `:scope` for the purpose of this question like so:

In your controller:

```
def index
  @watchlists = Watchlist.belongs_to_user(current_user)
  render json: @watchlists,
    each_serializer: WatchlistOnlySerializer,
    context: { currency: params[:currency] }
end
```

Then you can access it in the serializer like so:

```
def market_value
  # this is where I'm trying to pass the parameter
  Balance.watchlist_market_value(self.id, context[:currency])
end
```

Comment: This one errors:
`NameError (undefined local variable or method 'instance_options' for #<V1::WatchlistOnlySerializer:0x007fb9c06e4638>`

Comment: your AMS version pls?

Comment: AMS Version 0.9.7

Comment: updated my answer for this version. please check out.

Comment: I'm on 0.10.9 and there's no such method.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `scope` in controller:

```
def index
 @watchlists = Watchlist.belongs_to_user(current_user)
 render json: @watchlists, each_serializer: WatchlistOnlySerializer, scope: { currency: params[:currency] }
end
```

And in your serializer:

```
def market_value
  Balance.watchlist_market_value(self.id, scope[:currency])
end
```

Comment: This works. Wasif Hossain has a more thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can send your params to your serializer like this

```
render json: @watchlists, each_serializer: WatchlistOnlySerializer, current_params: currency
```

and in your serializer you can use this to get the value

```
serialization_options[:current_params]
```